# write code directly in aspx page in gridview to access server side properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, gridview

I have a gridview which contains few Template columns, In the first Template column , I have a LinkButton (Visible bydefault) and a Label(Hidden bydefault).

I have setup a property (IsPopup) on server side (aspx.cs file)

Now my requirement is to Show LinkButton and hide Label if IsPopup is true and vice versa.

Following is the code sample

aspx.cs code

```
public bool IsPopup
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

aspx code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvEquipment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource2">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblCheckPointCode" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblCheckPointCodeResource1"
           Text='<%# Bind("CheckPointCode") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCheckPointCode" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
           meta:resourcekey="lbtnCheckPointCodeResource1" Text='<%# Bind("CheckPointCode") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
     </asp:TemplateField>

   </Columns>

 </asp:GridView>
```

In the above code you can see the Label is visible false bydefault.

When I tried to implement Visible='<# IsPopup '

following error appears:
Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<# IsPopup ' for the 'Visible' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblCheckPointCode" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblCheckPointCodeResource1"
       Text='<%# Bind("CheckPointCode") %>' Visible='<%# IsPopup '></asp:Label>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCheckPointCode" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
       meta:resourcekey="lbtnCheckPointCodeResource1" Text='<%# Bind("CheckPointCode") %>' Visible='<%# !IsPopup '></asp:LinkButton>
```

[Edit] another approach, you can handle the RowCreated Event :

```
void ProductsGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    var lbl = e.Row.FindControl("lblCheckPointCode");
    if(lbl != null) lbl.Visible = !IsPopup;

    var lnk= e.Row.FindControl("lbtnCheckPointCode");
    if(lnk!= null) lbl.Visible = !IsPopup;



}
```

Comment: I am getting following error:     Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<# IsPopup ' for the 'Visible' property.

Comment: Try adding % i.e. Visible='<%# IsPopup %>'

Comment: @AlanStephens: good point :). I updated my post, but I kept the second approach as it is also valid.

Comment: thats perfect, I'll prefer the first approach , I feel the second approach is outdated and does not require if you have property defined.

Comment: @ImranRizvi: the second approach allows more complex rules (you can call external method) and can be mandatory in such cases (I prefer MVC for this reason... more clear and more flexible).

Comment: thats true, but specific to my problem I feel the first approach is short and perfect.

Comment: glad to have helped you anyways:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Visible='<%# Bind("IsPopup ") %>'` to set visible true or false of control.

Comment: That's wrong, IsPopup is not in my datasource, following error comes:  DataBinding: 'DataSource1' does not contain a property with the name 'IsPopup'.

Comment: You have to add a boolean property in your datasource or anyother property which triggers you to set control visible. Bind that property to visible='<%# Bind("<propertyname>")>'

Comment: Thats not my requirement. I can't add anything in my datasource